# extract multi columns based on values of specific column

Tags: matlab, search, indexing, row

I'm working on a data that is in a 4x4 matrix. a sample of this matrix would be like below:

```
2361.31888  2   3   0.03848284
2351.31888  2   3   0.03828271
2341.31888  2   3   0.03583279
2331.31888  2   3   0.03613991
2511.31888  3   3   0.09945525
2501.31888  3   3   0.10257245
2491.31888  3   3   0.08145624
```

The 2nd column values would be from `2` to `1500`. what I want to do is extract 1st and 4th columns values when 2nd column is 2 and do it till I reach 1500 for 2nd column.

For example i need this rows when the 2nd column is 2 and want to calculate linear regression for this sub-matrix. This should be done for the rest of the original matrix too.

```
    2361.31888  0.03848284
    2351.31888  0.03828271
    2341.31888  0.03583279
    2331.31888  0.03613991
```

And calculate linear regression for extracted columns. I wrote the code like this but it doesn't work properly.

```
for i = unique(D(:,2))'
    if D(:,2)==i        
        X(i) = D(:,1) ;
        Y(i) = D(:,4) ;
        n = numel(X(i));

        % // Define relevant quantities for finding quantities
        sumxi = sum(X(i));
        sumyi = sum(Y(i));
        sumxiyi = sum(X(i).*Y(i));
        sumxi2 = sum(X(i).^2);
        sumyi2 = sum(Y(i).^2);

        %// Determine slope and intercept
        m(i) = (sumxi * sumyi - n*sumxiyi) / (sumxi^2 - n*sumxi2);
        b(i) = (sumxiyi * sumxi - sumyi* sumxi2) / (sumxi^2 - n*sumxi2);
    end
end
```

Comment: "Doesn't work properly" how?

Comment: It doesn't give the m and b for each sub-matrices.

Comment: Exactly what values do you want to ignore?

Comment: What do you mean "ignore"?  it's ok if i just know how should i get those sub-matrices i can calculate the linear regression afterwards.

Comment: In other word this code does not extract the 1nd and 4nd column for each values of 2nd column.

Comment: So in the above example you want **only** `2361.31888    0.03848284` and `2511.31888    0.09945525` and ignore all the other rows? (I'm asking this because I see you are using `unique` so I am a bit confused. Please clarify)

Comment: Well, i want this rows `2361.31888    0.03848284,
2351.31888    0.03828271,
2341.31888    0.03583279,
2331.31888    0.03613991` when the 2nd column is 2 and calculate the regression for this columns. and continue till the end of matrix.

Comment: Ok now it makes sense. You should clarify this in your question.

Comment: @Marco Done, hope it would be more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract rows based on column values in a matrix you can use logicals in array indexing

```
>> D = [ 2361.31888  2   3   0.03848284; ...
         2351.31888  2   3   0.03828271; ...
         2341.31888  2   3   0.03583279; ...
         2331.31888  2   3   0.03613991; ...
         2511.31888  4   3   0.09945525; ...
         2501.31888  4   3   0.10257245; ... 
         2491.31888  4   3   0.08145624 ];

>> indexes_where_2nd_col_is_2 = ( D(:,2) == 2 )

indexes_where_2nd_col_is_2 =

  7×1 logical array

   1
   1
   1
   1
   0
   0
   0

>> D(indexes_where_2nd_col_is_2, :)

ans =

   2361.31888  2   3   0.03848284
   2351.31888  2   3   0.03828271
   2341.31888  2   3   0.03583279
   2331.31888  2   3   0.03613991
```

To make this work in your loop you can do something like

```
for i = unique(D(:,2))'
    M = D(D(:,2) == i, :);
    X(i) = M(:,1);
    Y(i) = M(:,4);

    % Rest of your code...
end
```

Comment: And if i want to do this for 1500 values? how should i put it in for loop?

Comment: Just to make it correct i should put X and Y in a cell like: `X{i} = M(:,1);
    Y{i} = M(:,4);`

Answer (score -1):

You can extract the two columns of interest by identifying the indices of the occurrence of the starting value (2) and the ending value (1500):

Then you can use the function `unique` to find the unique value in the second column.

If you call `unique` asking for three output values, you will get the indices of the occurrence of the set of the unique values

At this point you can loop over these indices to extract the single sub set of data.

The following code extracts:

- `sub_m`: the whole submatrix with the second column valus between 2 and 1500
  -`first_column`: the data of only the first column
- `fourth_column`: the data of ony the fourth column
- `sub_data`: a struct array with the fields: `unique_values` the unique value in the column 2, `first_column`: the data of the first column corresponding to the unique val, `fourth_column`: the data of the fourth column corresponding to the unique val

The code for test purpose I've modified your original matrix:

```
m_data=[
2361.31888    2   3   0.03848284
2351.31888    2   3   0.03828271
2341.31888    2   3   0.03583279
2331.31888    2   3   0.03613991
2511.31888    3   3   0.09945525
2501.31888    3   3   0.10257245
2491.31888    4   3   0.08145624
2491.31888    4   3   0.08145624
2491.31888    4   3   0.08145624
1234.31888 1500   3  13.08145624
5678.31888 1500   3  33.08145624
];

% Define the desired initial value
initial_val=2;
% Define the desired final value
final_val=1500;
% FInd the indices of the data in the second column equal to the initial value
idx_1=find(m_data(:,2) == initial_val)
% FInd the indices of the data in the second column equal to the final value
idx_2=find(m_data(:,2) == final_val)
% The start index is the first element of the set
start_idx=idx_1(1)
% The final index is the index of hte first occurrence of the final value -1
final_idx=idx_2(1)-1
% The whole sub matrix is:
sub_m=m_data(start_idx:final_idx,:)
% The second column of the sub matrix is:
first_column=m_data(start_idx:final_idx,1)
% The fourth column of the sub matrix is:
fourth_column=m_data(start_idx:final_idx,4)
% Get the unique values
[unique_values,a,b]=unique(m_data(start_idx:final_idx,2))
% Esxtract the set of data for the unique values
sub_data(1).val=unique_values(1)
sub_data(1).first_column=first_column(1:a(1))
sub_data(1).fourth_column=fourth_column(1:a(1))
for i=2:length(unique_values)
   sub_data(i).val=unique_values(i)
   sub_data(i).first_column=first_column(a(i-1)+1:a(i))
   sub_data(i).fourth_column=fourth_column(a(i-1)+1:a(i))
end
```

The output:

```
sub_m =

  2.3613e+003  2.0000e+000  3.0000e+000  3.8483e-002
  2.3513e+003  2.0000e+000  3.0000e+000  3.8283e-002
  2.3413e+003  2.0000e+000  3.0000e+000  3.5833e-002
  2.3313e+003  2.0000e+000  3.0000e+000  3.6140e-002
  2.5113e+003  3.0000e+000  3.0000e+000  9.9455e-002
  2.5013e+003  3.0000e+000  3.0000e+000  1.0257e-001
  2.4913e+003  4.0000e+000  3.0000e+000  8.1456e-002
  2.4913e+003  4.0000e+000  3.0000e+000  8.1456e-002
  2.4913e+003  4.0000e+000  3.0000e+000  8.1456e-002

>> first_column

first_column =

   2361.3
   2351.3
   2341.3
   2331.3
   2511.3
   2501.3
   2491.3
   2491.3
   2491.3

>> fourth_column

fourth_column =

   0.038483
   0.038283
   0.035833
   0.036140
   0.099455
   0.102572
   0.081456
   0.081456
   0.081456
>> sub_data(1)
ans =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    val =  2
    first_column =

       2361.3
       2351.3
       2341.3
       2331.3

    fourth_column =

       0.038483
       0.038283
       0.035833
       0.036140


>> sub_data(2)
ans =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    val =  3
    first_column =

       2511.3
       2501.3

    fourth_column =

       0.099455
       0.102572

>> sub_data(3)
ans =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    val =  4
    first_column =

       2491.3
       2491.3
       2491.3

    fourth_column =

       0.081456
       0.081456
       0.081456
```